Need help writing a SQL for a parent child relationship
I am trying to write a SQL that retrieves parent-child relationships from the product data, including a calculated Consolidated Quantity. The consolidated quantity is derived by multiplying the child's quantity by the parent's quantity recursively, considering multiple levels of hierarchy.
Table Structure:
Product Table:
ID: Primary key, unique identifier for the product.
Name: The name of the product.
Relationships Table:
Product_ID: Foreign key, referencing the Product.ID field (parent product).
Child_Product_ID: Foreign key, referencing the Product.ID field (child product).
Child_Product_name: The name of the child product.
QTY: The quantity of the child product needed for the parent product.
Example Case:
Parent A has two child products:
B1 with quantity 2
B2 with quantity 3
B1 has a child C1 with quantity 1
B2 has a child C2 with quantity 2
The output should be:
A, B1, 2
A, B2, 3
A, C1, 2 (Consolidated quantity: 2 B1 * 1 C1)
A, C2, 6 (Consolidated quantity: 3 B2 * 2 C2)

Same SQL
-- Create Product Table
CREATE TABLE Product (
    ID NUMBER(3), 
    Name VARCHAR2(100)
);

-- Create Relationships Table
CREATE TABLE Relationships (
    Product_ID NUMBER(3),  
    Child_Product_ID NUMBER(3),
    Child_Product_Name VARCHAR2(100), 
    QTY NUMBER(10)
);

-- Insert into Product Table with 3-digit IDs
INSERT INTO Product (ID, Name) VALUES
(100, 'A'),   -- A
(200, 'B1'),  -- B1
(300, 'B2'),  -- B2
(400, 'C1'),  -- C1
(500, 'C2');  -- C2

-- Insert into Relationships Table with Child Product Name
INSERT INTO Relationships (Product_ID, Child_Product_ID, Child_Product_Name, QTY) VALUES
(100, 200, 'B1', 2),  -- A needs 2 B1
(100, 300, 'B2', 3),  -- A needs 3 B2
(200, 400, 'C1', 1),  -- B1 needs 1 C1
(300, 500, 'C2', 2);  -- B2 needs 2 C2

Output
I tried writing recursive queries but did not get the desired output

Please share what you have tried and sample output

Don't include Child_Product_Name in the relationships table. It is already in the Product table and if you have it in both places then you can get out-of-sync.

Use a recursive query and then JOIN to the Product table to get the names:
WITH hierarchy (product_id, child_product_id, qty) AS (
  SELECT product_id, child_product_id, qty
  FROM   relationships
  WHERE  Product_id = 100
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.product_id, r.child_product_id, h.qty * r.qty
  FROM   hierarchy h
         INNER JOIN relationships r
         ON h.child_product_id = r.product_id
)
SELECT p.name,
       c.name AS child_name,
       h.qty
FROM   hierarchy h
       INNER JOIN Product P ON h.product_id = p.id
       INNER JOIN Product C ON h.child_product_id = c.id

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



NAME
CHILD_NAME
QTY




A
B1
2


A
B2
3


B1
C1
2


B2
C2
6



fiddle
